# Sort scrambled two-dimensional array filled with numbers by swapping adjacent numbers

Tags: code-challenge, array, sorting

A two-dimensional array of size n×n is filled with n*n numbers, starting from number 1. Those numbers are to be sorted per row in ascending order; the first number of a row must be greater than the last number of the previous row (the smallest number of all (1) will be in [0,0]). This is similar to the [15 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle).

This is, for example, a sorted array of size *n = 3*.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

### Input

The input is a scrambled array. It can be of any size up to n = 10. Example for n = 3:

```
4 2 3
1 8 5
7 9 6
```

### Output

Output a list of *swaps* required to sort the array. A *swap* is defined as following: **Two *adjacent* numbers swap positions, either horizontally or vertically; diagonal swapping is not permitted.**

Example output for the example above:

- Swap 4 and 1
- Swap 8 and 5
- Swap 8 and 6
- Swap 9 and 8

**The less swaps required, the better.** Computation time must be feasible.

---

Here is another example input, with n = 10:

```
41 88 35 34 76 44 66 36 58 28
6 71 24 89 1 49 9 14 74 2
80 31 95 62 81 63 5 40 29 39
17 86 47 59 67 18 42 61 53 100
73 30 43 12 99 51 54 68 98 85
13 46 57 96 70 20 82 97 22 8
10 69 50 65 83 32 93 45 78 92
56 16 27 55 84 15 38 19 75 72
33 11 94 48 4 79 87 90 25 37
77 26 3 52 60 64 91 21 23 7
```

If I'm not mistaken, this would require around 1000-2000 swaps.

Comment: Is this a puzzle, speed, or golfing problem?

Comment: @MichaelKlein This is a puzzle.

Comment: Is it scored? What ranges need to be handled?

Comment: @MichaelKlein The lower the number of swaps, the better the solution is.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. All questions on this site are required to be challenges, with a winning criterion to compare all valid answers against each other. I would suggest code golf (shortest code), as there is quite an efficient algorithm for this in an optimal number of swaps. But I would insist that  the solution be optimal and that it complete in under a minute for n=1000. (It's impossible for your n=10 example to have more that 100 swaps.)

Comment: @steveverrill I'm afraid it is quite impossible to solve the n=10 example in less than 100 swaps (or even 1000; but please prove me wrong). Still, the number of swaps is the winning criterion (though computation must be feasible!), the one who comes up with a solution with the lowest number of swaps wins.

Comment: @JCarter I think you meant to say that only adjacent numbers may be swapped?

Comment: @quintopia that's what I was missing

Comment: @steveverrill yes, otherwise you are right that any 10x10 array can be sorted in under 200 swaps

Comment: @steveverrill Oh, you are right! Only adjacent numbers can swap (horizontally and vertically but not diagonally). I must have forgot to put it in the description. I've added it now, thanks!

Comment: What is the distribution of inputs for the win conditions? Also, "feasible" computation time is too loose.

Comment: @xnor The win condition is met when the array is fully sorted. Feasible computation time should mean that it should take no longer than 5 minutes on a standard desktop PC to compute.

Comment: @JCarter -0.1 for "standard desktop PC". Seriously, the average desktop computer of Jan '10 is 64 times slower than the average desktop computer of Jan '16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mathematica, not golfed

```
towards[a_,b_]:={a,a+If[#==0,{0,Sign@Last[b-a]},{#,0}]&@Sign@First[b-a]};
f[m_]:=Block[{m2=Map[QuotientRemainder[#-1,10]+1&,m,{2}]},
  Rule@@@Apply[10(#1-1)+#2&,#,{2}]&@
    Reap[Table[
      m2=NestWhile[
        Function[{x},x/.(Sow[#];Thread[#->Reverse@#])&[x[[##]]&@@@towards[First@Position[x,i,{2}],i]]]
        ,m2,#~Extract~i!=i&];
      ,{i,Reverse/@Tuples[Range[10],2]}];][[2,1]]]
```

---

**Explanation**:

The algorithm is similar to "bubble sort". These 100 numbers are put into correct order one by one, `1, 11, 21, ..., 91; 2, ..., 92; ...; 10, ..., 100`. They are first move up/down to the correct rows, and then move left to the correct columns.

Function `towards` gives the two position to swap. For example, if `{5,2}` is moving to `{1,1}`, `towards[{5,2},{1,1}]` gives `{{5,2},{5,1}}` (move up); and  `towards[{5,1},{1,1}]` gives `{{5,1},{4,1}}` (move left).

---

**Results**:

For the test case, the total number of swaps is 558. The first few swaps are,

```
{1->76,1->34,1->35,1->88,1->41,11->16,11->69,11->46, ...
```

For a random configuration, the total number of swaps is **558.5 ± 28.3** (1σ).

[image]